# What function should I use to filter a text file for any element in array?

Tags: python, list

I have a list of words that I'm trying to filter from a text file stored in an array, but I'm not sure what function to use. Here's my code:

```
words = ["liverpool","arsenal","chelsea","manutd","mancity"]
test = ["LiverpoolFan","ArsenalFan"]
test2 = []

for i in range (len(test)):
    test2[i] = test[i].lower()
    if *any word in words* in test2[i]:
        print("True")
```

I've used a test array to simulate reading from a text file.
I'm not sure what to use inbetween the two **

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use builtin [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

```
>>> test2 = [team for team in words 
             if any(team.lower() in fanbase.lower() for fanbase in test)]
>>> test2
['liverpool', 'arsenal']
```

Or `any` with [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter):

```
>>> def check_match(team):
        return any(team.lower() in fanbase.lower() for fanbase in test)
>>> test2 = list(filter(check_match, words))
>>> test2
['liverpool', 'arsenal']
```

Or you could use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) with a separator that is not in your `words` list, such as `','`:

```
>>> all_fans = ','.join(test).lower()
>>> test2 = [team for team in words if team in all_fans]
>>> test2
['liverpool', 'arsenal']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```py
words = ["liverpool","arsenal","chelsea","manutd","mancity"]
fans = ["LiverpoolFan","ArsenalFan"]

for fan in fans:
  for word in words:
    if word.lower() in fan.lower():
      print(f"{word} in {fan}", True)
```

Answer (score 0):

brute force approach. Checks for every item if any word from words contains it

```
matches = []
for item in test:
    for word in words:
       # word.lower() thanks to  @sushanth
       if item.lower() in word.lower():
           matches.append(item)
           print("True")
```

Comment: @Sushanth Added it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple attempt, you can simply remove *Fan* from the `test` in order to check if there is team in `words` match that in `test`

```
import re

words = ["liverpool","arsenal","chelsea","manutd","mancity"]
test = ["LiverpoolFan","ArsenalFan"]
purified_test = [re.sub('Fan','', i) for i in test]
print(test)
for i in words:
    if i.title() in test:
        print('True');
```

or make it `lower()` while removing *Fan*

```
purified_test = [re.sub('Fan','', i).lower() for i in test]
for i in words:
    if i in purified_test:
        print('True');
```

or you can append it to test_2 and get the array like the following

```
import re
words = ["liverpool","arsenal","chelsea","manutd","mancity"]
test = ["LiverpoolFan","ArsenalFan"]
test2 = []


purified_test = [re.sub('Fan','', i).lower() for i in test]
for i in words:
    if i in purified_test:
        test2.append(i)
print(test2)
```

output

```
['liverpool', 'arsenal']
```

if all files don't all end in fan you can simple make the character set of all words that ends it like the following

```
import re
regex = re.compile('(Fan|FC|etc)')
```

Comment: Unfortunately all the lines in the notepad file don't all end in fan, some of them look like "LiverpoolFC!!"